# How to create upload form with fwrite php

Tags: php

I am create upload form by fwrite function php.
My code is here

```
<?php
$file = fopen("C:/xampp/htdocs/eibak/sss.php","w");

echo fwrite($file,"<?php
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $file = $_FILES['file']['name']; 
    $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $dir = '';
    echo $dir;
    if (move_uploaded_file($temp, $dir.$file)) { 
        $link = $dir.$file; 
    ?>
    <?php } } ?>
    <form action='' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <input type='file' name='file'/>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/>
    </form>");
fclose($file);
?>
```

But Parse error: syntax error,

> unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier
>   (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\exploit\ff.php on line 5 error show.

How to create upload form with file write php.

Comment: @Dave The OP wants to write a php file by means of php. The `<?php` is required inside that php file, without that the file cannot be used later.

Comment: It is unclear what you try to achieve with this. Would you care to elaborate what you actually want to happen?

Comment: I am trying to create simple upload form with fwrite php function.

Comment: Sorry, but repeating what you already wrote does not help when you are asked to elaborate.

Comment: @Dragon Sorry, but where is the connection between this question and the one you declared it to be a duplicate of?